# VM Ware vsphere ESXi6.5にてOVAをデプロイするとエラーが発生する。

Tags: vmware

下記の環境でOVAをデプロイしようとすると下記のエラーメッセージが出て最終的にデプロイが完了しません。Webで検索をすると分散SWのポートグループでは無く、標準SWのポートグループに変更をすれば良いとの記載がありました。
https://server.etutsplus.com/ovf-deployment-fails-with-the-error-virtual-ide-controller-1-0/
しかしながらその理由が書いておらず、また分散SWのポートグループから標準SWのポートグループに変更するのは環境を大幅に変更する必要があるため、理由を教えてください。もしくはこれ以外の回避策を教えてください。

エラーメッセージ
指定された生成ファイルのチェックサムが 「hoge-vm.vmdk」 ファイルの内容と一致しません

環境
IEを使用してvsphereにアクセス。
ESXiは6.5？
CPUやメモリ等は不足無し。

Answer (score 1):

IEを使用してvsphereにアクセスをしていたのが原因だったようです。
これは推測ですがIEには4ギガを超えるデータをうまく転送できない事があるみたいで、
chromeにadobe falash playerをインストールするとデプロイが完了します。